# Why is there no tag for Wolfram Development Platform?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Why is there no tag for [Wolfram Development Platform](http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/?src=google&1100&gclid=CJK5u9PR3sgCFQIYwwodEiYM0A)?

Comment: Because the community chose to go with karsten's suggestion in the Q&A that I linked to here above.

Comment: Having a [tag:development-platform] or [tag:wolfram-development-platform] tag as an additional synonym for [tag:wolfram-cloud] would make sense, though.

Answer (score 8):

I have made [wolfram-development-platform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-development-platform) a [synonym](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/wolfram-cloud/synonyms) of [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud).

Comment: Bad idea I think, given it does not accord with Wolfram official terminology http://i.imgur.com/45xraSO.png .

Comment: @Chris, and, what does it say on the upper left corner of the page you took your screenshot from?

Comment: @ChrisJJ You shouldn't care too much about the "official terminology". It is changed, extended or prefixed with *Wolfram* every couple of months.

Comment: The fact it changes doesn't sound like good enough reason not to care.

Comment: @J. M. Can't you read it?  It is the address of the web page. Which unfortunately this form distorts if I enter it here.

Comment: @Chris, I mean the **logo** at the upper left corner of the *page*, not the screenshot. A *page* and a *screenshot* are two different things.

Comment: @J. M. It says Wolfram Cloud (truncated) with nothing indicating that's a synonym of Wolfram Development Platform.